# Getting [ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found error after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odbc

I deployed a project in Windows Server 2008 r2 64 bit and getting following error

ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Following connection string I am using

```
<add name="thisconnect" connectionString="Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=1.2.4/thisdb;Uid= uname;
Pwd= pname;" providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>
```

Guide How I remove this error

Answer (score 0):

Most likely means that the driver is not installed. Maybe you only have 32 bit driver?

Comment: Actually I am a finding a driver Windows Server 2008 r2 64 bit but unable to find it.Do you know any driver